How is the 3D Perspective Camera transformation implemented in JavaFX?
I'm looking for a way to map a point in 3D eye space to its equivalent window coordinates, but I can't seem to find any information about how JavaFX does it.

See PerspectiveCamera.java, it uses a viewing frustum

It looks like the project function in Camera.java is what I need.

I was able to perform the 3D point mapping that I wanted by making Camera.project accessible.  It would be nice, though, if there were a public way to do it.  Qt has the public functions Camera::mapToViewport and Camera::mapFromViewport that have this capability.

node.localToScreen is somewhat similar.  It is not the same, but might form a component of calculating the value using a public API.  You would need to adjust the result by the viewport location on the screen, and the node would need to be in a scene attached to a window.  You could file an enhancement request for the methods you would like.

Silly me. I just learned about PickResult.  It does exactly what I need and it's public.  I won't need to file any enhancement requests.  Thanks, everyone.

Oh, it was an xyproblem, after all :-)
